# Reduce events in dynamic menu in AngularJS?

Tags: events, angularjs, menu, watch

I've built a dynamic menu which also have highlighting.
 Now i got a problem, number of path-change events are increasing along with menu elements.
Of course, that's the result of applying directive on each element of the menu.

Custom directives at the moment is my most weak place, and i don't have idea how to refactor all this.
I also made an attempt to put directive in root element of menu (ul) in order to register watch once, but stuck on accessing the deep children elements (ul->li->a.href).

Here's the directive:

```
app.directive("testdir", function($location)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.$watch(function() { return $location.path(); }, function(path)
            {
                scope.$parent.firedEvents++;
                path=path.substring(1);
                if(path === element.children().attr("href").substring(2))
                {
                    element.addClass("activeLink");
                }
                else
                {
                    element.removeClass("activeLink");
                }
            })
        }

    };
```

And HTML Part:

```
<ul ng-app="test" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="link in menuDef" testdir><a href="{{link.url}}">{{link.linkName}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Whole example [**on JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHzLe/2/)

How this can be refactored? I'm exhausted.
and, i'm moving in the right direction? I have a feeling that this thing could be done in bit easier way, but maybe i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `firedEvents` means how many time the callback has been called, not how many times the location actually changed, it's not the "number of path-change events"!

You have 20 (as in your fiddle) scopes are watching the location change, when you click on a different link other than the current active one, the location changes, **ALL** of the 20 scopes will see the change and call their **own** `$watch` callback functions, and each call to the callback will increase your `firedEvents`, so the result is what you have seen: the count goes up by 20.

Therefore, if you want to make the `firedEvents` to count how many time location has changed, you should move `scope.$parent.firedEvents++;` into the `if`. But keep in mind that every click will still cause the callback function be called by 20 times!

There are many ways to achieve the same effect you're trying to do here, I have a solution for you without digging into directive at all. Here you go:

HTML

```
<ul ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="link in menuDef" ng-class="{activeLink: link.isActive}" ng-click="onLinkClick(link)"><a href="{{link.url}}">{{link.linkName}}</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
app.controller("MenuCtrl", function ($scope, $location) {
    var menugen = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        menugen.push({
            linkName: "Link " + i,
            url: "#/url" + i
        });
    }
    $scope.menuDef = menugen;

    var activeLink = null;
    $scope.onLinkClick = function (link) {
        if (activeLink && $scope.activeLink !== link) {
            activeLink.isActive = false;
        }
        link.isActive = true;
        activeLink = link;
    };
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaux/rRgE5/)</kbd>

### Update

My first attempt is targeting simplicity, but as @VirtualVoid pointed out, it has a huge drawback -- it can't easily handle location change from outside of the menu.

Here, I came up a better solution: adding a directive to the `ul`, watch location change in there, *and* update activeLink in the callback function of the watch. In this way, one `$watch` is called, and only one callback will be called for a click.

JS

```
app.directive('menu', function ($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function ($scope, $location) {
            var links = [];

            this.registerLink = function (elem, path) {
                links.push({
                    elem: elem,
                    path: path
                });
            };

            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return $location.path();
            }, function (path) {
                for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                    if (path === links[i].path) {
                        links[i].elem.addClass('activeLink');
                    } else {
                        links[i].elem.removeClass('activeLink');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
}).
directive("testdir", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^menu',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            controller.registerLink(element, scope.link.url.substring(1));
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<ul ng-app="test" ng-controller="MenuCtrl" menu>
    <li ng-repeat="link in menuDef" testdir>
        <a href="{{link.url}}">{{link.linkName}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaux/MFYCX/

Comment: That's nice. Thanks. But this variant has a one disadvantage, it doesn't listens to path changes and any other link (which isn't present in menu) will have no effect on highlighting.
Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/rRgE5/2/
By the way, i did some refactor and now i have one event producer and 20 consumers (which is li tags), that's alot better imho.
It's here: http://jsfiddle.net/eHzLe/3/
Unfortunatelly, this one have a problem too. The first "pathChange" event happens too early, while as, the directives aren't yet listening for the events. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Looks like i coped with last problem. Dunno though, if this correct or not. Here it goes: http://jsfiddle.net/eHzLe/4/

Comment: @VirtualVoid One $watch call definitely looks better, but you still have 20 event handlers will be called on each click, it's bad for performance. I'm going to update my answer with better solution.

Comment: That's great! Finally, thanks alot. By the way, ehm, seems the final solution are having the same problem as in previous. I mentioned above about early watch event. Path are changing, before the link registrations. For example, if page is just opening with any url, e.g #/url5, the menu will remain unhighlighted. Now i can't manage this, getting '$digest already in progress' :/

Comment: @VirtualVoid I've updated the fiddle to handle the first location change issue